# How to configure Jasmine in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea, jasmine

I have done all steps from this article *[How to configure IntelliJ for Angular JS testing](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-configure-intellij-idea-for-angular-js-testing/)*.

I have add [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) as a one of JS libs in `Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`:

[image]

[image]

But my specs files still can't recognize Jasmine API and functions as `describe`, `beforeEach`, `it` and ... highlighted as *Unresolved functions or methods...*:

[image]

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Anton Dozortsev",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-jade": "^0.9.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "should": "^8.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.4",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

So what I miss while configuring Jasmine ?

Comment: can I see your package.json file?

Comment: @Sai Sure. Check updates.

Comment: Didn't you install angular-mocks?

Comment: @Sai Yes but as Bower component.

Comment: No problem. In your angular code you have to refer to that file in bower_components and add `'ngMock'` module to main app module.

Comment: @Sai It doesn't help. Why you decide that issue with Angular Mock ?

Comment: Iam not deciding. I just try to make sure it is not the problem.